# Angular code not working when moved to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to figure out why code that works fine when written directly in a file suddenly doesn't render when I split it out into a directive.

I have the following:

app.js

```
...
    app.directive('facilityImage', function(config){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateURL: "/includes/facility-image-dsp.html"
    };
});
....
```

/includes/facility-image-dsp.html

```
<div ng-controller="FacImgController" style="text-align:center; width: 100%;">
    <div class="imgblock" ng-repeat="item in facImages" ng-show="item.page == '{{myFunctions.subtabname}}'">
        <img src="{{item.image}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

exam.html

```
<facility-image></facility-image>
```

I get a blank page and the error logs say there's no such file called  {{item.image}}.

Things to note:

1) The code in the directive, when placed directly in exam.html, works perfectly.

2) exam.html is actually loaded via $http.get() into a div in index.php. The site never leaves index.php. All subpages are retrieved via $http.get() and replace the contents of the content div. I had some trouble with that until I learned how to "re-compile" the page and it made the Angular render properly. However, now, with the directive piece added in, it doesn't anymore.

What am I missing here that the code doesn't work simply because I moved it to a directive?

EDIT:  Something funky just happened which led to me testing a slightly different way and it seems that I was mistaken. It doesn't even seem to be loading the file in the templateURL field! The problem may be that!  Thoughts? I can't see what's wrong in my directive call.

EDIT TWO:  After further testing and scouring logs, I don't even think that `<facility-image></facility-image>` is even calling the directive in the first place!! I changed it to `restrict: 'A'` and then `<div facility-image></div>` in the HTML and added

```
link: function(){
    alert("I'm working!");
    }
```

and got nothing.  So, it seems my problem may be further up the chain. Any reason that anyone can think of as to why the custom call wouldn't be working. Feel free to even throw out the Captain Obvious ideas since I've been looking at this code a while and may be overlooking the simplest thing at this point!

Comment: Can you try using ng-src?

Comment: I guess I could, but I'm trying to figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: But this could possibly be your issue: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Comment: But it works perfectly when in the file (exam.html). It only fails once I move it into the directive. So I'm trying to figure out what makes it fail once I cross that line. How am I losing the functionality simply because I put it in a directive?

Comment: Putting it in a directive may have some other consequences which cause it to load slower which could mean that the src is loaded first before angular kicks in

Comment: In the end, I'm using `
<div ng-include src="'/includes/facility-image-dsp.html'"></div>` but I'm still wondering why my custom directive isn't even being called.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!  Came back to this with fresh eyes today and figured it out.

The problem was that I had written

templateURL

instead of

templateUrl

Apparently it's case-sensitive! 
Works fine now!